# firebase onSnapshot how to refresh arrays to avoid duplicate in an array in react native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make a function to listen to the firestore database, but everytime it runs, the values in the array get duplicated. Simple the array keep adding up the values. How can i make sure the array is empty every-time something changes in the database
here is the code i am using:

```
const Chat_Eventos = (props) => {

  const [chatInfo, setChatInfo] = useState([])
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  
  const fetch_info_events  = async () => {
   try{
      const fetchEventInfo = async(item) => {
        const unsub = onSnapshot(doc(db, "usersChat", item), (doc) => {
          setChatInfo(prevEvents => [...prevEvents, doc.data()])
        });
        return () => {
          unsub();
        };
      }
      for (const item of props.user_going) {
        await fetchEventInfo(item);
      }
    }catch(err){
      console.log(err)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch_info_events()
  },[props.user_going])
}
```

Comment: The Cloud Datastore, Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with all of them.